# Unknown app in Gnome Favorites bar

Tags: gnome, favorites

I have a unknown app in my favorites bar, as you can see from this screenshot (it's the 5th icon).

[Unknown app in favorites](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJxFj.png)

If I mouse-over, the tooltip displays my emailadress, and clicking on it gives me a context menu with the following options:
-new window (does'nt do anything)
-mount (afaik also doesn't do anything)
-add to favorites (doesn't do anything)
-show details (doesn't do anything)

as you can see the output of `gsettings get org.gnome.shell favorite-apps` doesn't include this unknown app.

Any ideas how to get rid of it?

Comment: Are there any apps with that icon in the overlay of all apps? Also, silly question but I need to ask it, have you tried dragging it from the bar to see if it removes it or transfer it to your desktop?